# How to Create a second DataSet by using SQL Statement on the First DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

How does one Create a second DataSet by using SQL Statement on the First DataSet.

There is an existing DataSet ds1 which contains tables "Customers" and "Orders" in it.

How can I create a second DataSet ds2 by passing a SQL Statement on the first ds1 DataSet.

The SQL Statement has a 'where clause' containing Fields from both "Customers" table and "Orders" table.

The second DataSet ds2 would be like a Filtered DataSet of ds1.

Thanx

Comment: You can't. There are various things you can do though. For example, you can create a `DataView`, set its `RowFilter` property and then call `ToTable` on it to get a new `DataTable`. No, I'm not going to write code for you. You can reseatch what I've told you, make your best attempt and then ask a new question if you encounter a specific issue. By the way, don't create a `DataSet` at all if you don't need one. If all you need is a single `DataTable` then just create that.

Comment: @John but when the select statement has joins, the result contains more than 1 table. So there is no question of just 1 table. You have to use a DataSet.

Comment: Um, no. A single `SELECT` statement only produces a single result set, regardless of how many tables it joins. If you are executing multiple `SELECT` statements then you will have multiple result sets, so having a `DataSet` containing multiple `DataTables` makes sense. There are also some situations where a `DataSet` with a single `DataTable` can make sense but, generally speaking, if you're only populating one `DataTable` then you should just have that one `DataTable` and no `DataSet`. I don't know whether that includes your situation or not but it might.

Comment: @john you are right, for a single Select statement with Join we can get a Single DataTable. In which we can easily Update values parent to child table wise. Also for Delete And we can use dt.Select() and get rows[] and delete those rows. But what about Insert? For that we need to insert Rows only in few tables. So for delete we will need separate DataTables like in a DataSet where we add rows only to the tables where we need to insert values.

Comment: Read my lips: use a `DataSet` if you need one and don't use a `DataSet` if you don't need one. Finding specific scenarios where you do need one doesn't change that, so why are you wasting your time and mine arguing the point? That's a rhetorical question that I don't want an answer to.

Comment: Sorry @John if i offended you. I was saying you were right about using DataTable. But I was asking what is the correct way to Insert Rows in the DataTable which was created using Select...From t1..Join t2

Comment: That has nothing to do with the topic of this question. Don't ask unrelated questions in the comments. If you have another valid question to ask, post it as a new question. I was simply offering advice that may improve what you're doing here. You can take it or leave it.

Comment: Thanx @john your answers earlier helped me understand that for a Select..Join SQL query we can use a DataTable. Thanx once again. I will post a new question for my other query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```sql
with ds1 as 
(query1),

select * 
from ds1
where order_id = 'x' and customer_id = 'y'
```